# How long does harvested yeast keep

Tags: yeast, harvest

Just like the title says: how long does harvested yeast keep? I am assuming to keep the yeast you have to store it in the refrigerator, right?

Comment: related to [Yeast Dead or Alive](http://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/6620/yeast-dead-or-alive)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *Yeast* (White & Zainasheff), they have a table of the reliable and max shelf life of yeast storage techniques:

- Harvested slurry: 2 weeks / 6 weeks
- Agar plate: 1 month / 1 year (if sealed)
- Agar slant: 3 months / 1-2 years
- Agar stab: 4 months / 2-3 years
- Water immersion: 6 months / 3-5 years

… &c., up to professional freezing.

People report success with fridge-stored slurry on much longer time frames.  I think White & Zainasheff are being somewhat pedantic; the amount of mutation you'll see in a handful of months is probably both very real, but also not particularly noticable to a homebrewer's beer or palate, all things considered.

You may want to look into yeast *washing* (using acid to help purify the harvested yeast) if you want to pursue that path.

Comment: Making a super light ferment occasionally and cropping from the krausen can be a great way to reselect the very healthy yeast strains from the yeast you have been storing.

Comment: How do you harvest yeast and store them in a water immersion?

Answer (score 2):

I've been washing yeast for years now and I've never had washed yeast be completely dead, even after 9 months, but that doesn't mean you should necessarily use it. If you do wash yeast, **ALWAYS** prepare a starter. This will let you know if the viability is good (if it propagates) and **smell the starter before pitching**. I have ruined two batches by pitching 'off-smelling' yeast washes. I am too cheap to leave the process alone; I have saved literally hundreds of dollars, but even one bad batch really pisses me off... Just remember, **any flavors you smell in the starter are going to be in your beer**; make sure you like them! Easy enough to run to the homebrew store and by some dry yeast or a smack pack! Good luck.

Comment: I have used a few yeasts that make some poor odors during high krausen that do not hold over to the actually beer. Smelling is a good idea, but people should probably compare to previous smells of the same strain.